# Docker linux container is not watching file changes made from Window host

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, window, centos7

I'm using a Docker image with `Centos 7` and `sbt` in order to run my scala application. I have my code running inside the container with `sbt run`, and a volume mapping this code to a Windows folder. Every time I modify a file on this Windows folder, the change is made inside the container too, but it's not detected by sbt watcher and the code is not compiled again automatically.

I read something about that and it seems to be related to this [issue](https://forums.docker.com/t/file-system-watch-does-not-work-with-mounted-volumes/12038/8). A workaround solution is [docker-windows-volume-watcher](http://blog.subjectify.us/miscellaneous/2017/04/24/docker-for-windows-watch-bindings.html) but it did not work for me.

How can I force sbt to detect the changes made from Window and recompile the code again automatically?